# SapUI5 Full Calendar Implementing Issue

Tags: fullcalendar, sapui5

I want to use FullCalendar for sapui5. But I'm getting an error while I was implementing that calendar. The error is about "registerPreloadedModules of undefined". When I removed the jquery.js file I'm not getting an error. I couldn't fix that problem. Where am I doing a mistake ?

Here is my code and error image;
[image]

Error;
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: ui5 contains a version of jquery, maybe it cannot handle it twice?

Comment: I've fixed the issue removing the jquery.js file. There isn't any error but fullCalendar object is not appearing. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @herrlock mentioned in the comment, SAPUI5 includes a version of jQuery.

If you don't want to or can't use that for your further implementation, have a look at [this page about a noJQuery variant](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f1dd0c6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html):
To use SAPUI5 without the bundled jQuery, include jQuery yourself before loading SAPUI5 and use `sap-ui-core-noJQuery.js` for bootstraping.

```html
<script src="my-jQuery-min.js"></script>
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"            
        src="resources/sap-ui-core-nojQuery.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried your methods. I'm not getting an error about jquery.js file. But fullCalendar object is not appearing. I'm using that code;<mvc:View
 controllerName="sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App"
 xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">

  <html:div id="calendar"></html:div>

</mvc:View>   What is the cause of this object may not appear? Thank you..

Comment: I can't go into specifics, as I have no idea what "FullCalendar" is, but in general, make sure that your script is only called after SAPUI5 rendering has finished if it is modifying DOM Elements inside the SAPUI5 ui-area.